# Convert mass into energy

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

When the mass is converted into energy, this means that the mass decreases and the energy increases, meaning that there is an inverse relationship between them. Is this true and what is the name of that energy? For example, there is kinetic energy, so what is this energy called?

Comment: Really there's no inverse proportionality at play here since if it were so, a gradually decreasing mass would give e gradually increasing energy up to infinity when the mass disappears. The relation between mass and energy is linear $E=\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$.

Comment: @DavideMorgante This is not linear.

Comment: @my2cts Yes of course. Maybe the rest frame version $E=m$ is better suited. The point is that there's no inverse relationship between them

Comment: When I mean an inverse relationship I mean E = the energy of the whole universe -mc^(2)

Answer (score 1):

The relation between mass and rest energy is the famous $$E=mc^2\,.$$ If mass is decreased in a nuclear reaction, the binding energy of the reaction products increases. This increase appears as kinetic energy and can be calculated from $$E^2 = m^2c^4 + p^2c^2$$.

Answer (score 1):

> When the mass is converted into energy, this means that the mass decreases and the energy increases, meaning that there is an inverse relationship between them.

The mass that is converted to energy is not the classical mechanics  mass of F=ma . If that could be done at normal energies and velocities, we would never had had the gold standard. Mass is conserved in classical mechanics and everyday. So there is no inverse relationship.

> what is the name of that energy? For example, there is kinetic energy, so what is this energy called?

Mass into energy conversion is an aspect of special relativity, the physics of large velocities and energies. The mathematics depends on four vectors , and here is the energy momentum four vector:

[image: fourvectoe]

Obeying vector algebra, there is an invariant "length" describing this four vector :

[image: finvmass]

> The length of this 4-vector is the rest energy of the particle. The invariance is associated with the fact that the rest mass is the same in any inertial frame of reference.

This is what we call the invariant mass of a particle.

Because of vector algebra, adding two four vectors, in general  a system of more particles, does not mean the masses add linearly, the vector addition gives a new vector with a new invariant mass. Suppose we add the four vectors of two free  protons and two free neutrons, their additive mass is larger than the mass of the quantum mechanically bound alpha particle. The difference is the binding energy. So the terms used for energy at this frame are not the simple ones of mechanics, but new ones, as "binding energy".

The m in $E=mc^2$ is the inertial mass of a relativistic particle, how much more force will be needed to accelerate it according to F=ma . As a concept it is useful for space travel, to calculate how much fuel is needed, but otherwise relativistic mass is no longer in use in particle physics because it confused the simple concepts of the four vectors. This inertial mass is the same with the invariant mass if the momentum is zero.